# Bash: history is lost after ssh connection is reset by peer: how to save the history?

Tags: bash, ssh, command-history

In my `.bashrc` I have already added:

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/40158199/9881330
function rescue_history {
    history -a
}
trap rescue_history SIGHUP
```

However, this does not work, because after `client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset by peer` the history is still lost. Which is very annoying since the useful entered commands are all lost!

The core question: How to configure `.bashrc` to save the history when ssh connection is reset by peer?

Very confused that this "history saving" behavior is not enabled by default.

My `.bashrc` also has also this (if it might help):

```
# new history settings
# http://jesrui.sdf-eu.org/remember-all-your-bash-history-forever.html
HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
HISTFILESIZE=-1
HISTSIZE=-1
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
#HISTIGNORE=?:??      # lines with one or two characters are discarded from the history (e.g. ls commands)
shopt -s histappend  # append to history, don't overwrite it
# attempt to save all lines of a multiple-line command in the same history entry
shopt -s cmdhist
# save multi-line commands to the history with embedded newlines
shopt -s lithist
```

Comment: You can modify `PROMPT_COMMAND` to save history after each command instead storing it in the memory and dumping it to the file when exiting which is the default behavior.

Comment: Question asks for Bash, but for those with zsh this is trivial to do. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389881/history-isnt-preserved-in-zsh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `PROMPT_COMMAND` special variable to run `history -a` every time you enter a command.

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+${PROMPT_COMMAND/%;};}history -a"
```

This will mix up commands from concurrent sessions which might make for a confusing scrollback.

To overcome that, here's a slightly more complicated version, which should create a time, tty and pid stamped file in your home directory, per session.

```
SESSION_HISTORY_FILE="${HOME}/bash_history_$(date -d "$(ps -olstart= -p$$ | awk '{print $2,$3,$5,$4}')" +%F_%H-%M-%S)$(tty | tr / _)_$$"
PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+${PROMPT_COMMAND/%;};}history -a '${SESSION_HISTORY_FILE}'"
```

The idea here being to create a properly contexted record of commands issued.

You wouldn't see these in scroll back for a terminated session (unless you added a `;history -a`).

Comment: Any idea on why `trap rescue_history SIGHUP` does not work in my case? Meaning that since `bash will (usually) receive a SIGHUP on disconnect` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/40158199/9881330), it seems that in my case bash does not receive SIGHUP on disconnect. But why? Both `sh --version` and `bash --version` give `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`.

Comment: I'm speculating, but I'd surmise that it's not receiving something as graceful as a HUP, more like a KILL.

Comment: Issue is found with this code: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/626303/bash-adding-history-a-to-prompt-command-makes-incorrect-calculation-of-last-co.