# Bash: adding history -a to PROMPT_COMMAND makes incorrect calculation of last command's wall time

Tags: bash, command-history, prompt, trap

To calculate last command's wall time I use this code (`code #1`):

```
#
# Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/34812608/9881330
# Slightly modified.
#
function timer_now {
    date +%s%N
}

function timer_start {
    timer_start=${timer_start:-$(timer_now)}
}

function timer_stop {
    local delta_us=$((($(timer_now) - $timer_start) / 1000))
    local us=$((delta_us % 1000))
    local ms=$(((delta_us / 1000) % 1000))
    local s=$(((delta_us / 1000000) % 60))
    local m=$(((delta_us / 60000000) % 60))
    local h=$((delta_us / 3600000000))
    # Goal: always show around 3 digits of accuracy
    if ((h > 0)); then timer_show=${h}h${m}m
    elif ((m > 0)); then timer_show=${m}m${s}s
    elif ((s >= 10)); then timer_show=${s}.$((ms / 100))s
    elif ((s > 0)); then timer_show=${s}.$(printf %03d $ms)s
    elif ((ms >= 100)); then timer_show=${ms}ms
    elif ((ms > 0)); then timer_show=${ms}.$((us / 100))ms
    else timer_show=${us}us
    fi
    unset timer_start
}

set_prompt () {
    PS1="\n\$?"
    timer_stop
    PS1+=" / $timer_show"
    PS1+="\n\n\[\e]0;\w\a\]\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$ "
}

trap 'timer_start' DEBUG
PROMPT_COMMAND='set_prompt'
```

And it works pretty well:

```
$ gcc
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

1 / 108ms

$ date
Sun Dec 27 14:53:10 RTZST 2020

0 / 89.3ms
```

However, to solve the `history is lost after ssh connection is reset by peer` problem ([Bash: history is lost after ssh connection is reset by peer: how to save the history?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/623700/bash-history-is-lost-after-ssh-connection-is-reset-by-peer-how-to-save-the-his)), after the previous code (`code #1`) I put this code (`code #2`):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="${PROMPT_COMMAND:+${PROMPT_COMMAND/%;};}history -a"
```

Now the last command's wall time is calculated incorrectly (while the commands visually run in a milliseconds as usual):

```
$ gcc
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

1 / 1.990s

$ date
Sun Dec 27 14:56:07 RTZST 2020

0 / 3.586s
```

Question: why adding `code #2` after `code #1` makes `code #1` produce incorrect results? How to fix?

Comment: Because you are measuring from `history -a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chain of events (it is assumed that reader knows what `${var:-someval}` works):

- You type some command.
- When you hit enter, `DEBUG` trap is executed.

  - `timer_start=${timer_start:-$(timer_now)}`
- Then the command is executed.
- Then `set_prompt` is executed.

  - Bla bla bla, then
  - `unset timer_start` - timer is restarted.
- Then `DEBUG` trap is executed before `history -a`

  - `timer_start=${timer_start:-$(timer_now)}`
- Then `history -a` is executed.
- Time passes, you type your command.
- Then `DEBUG` trap is executed before your typed command.

  - `timer_start=${timer_start:-$(timer_now)}`
  - but `timer_start` is already set, so nothing happens.
- Then your command is executed.
- `set_prompt` is super long, cause it measures time from the last `prompt_command` when `history -a` was executed.

Execute `history -a` for example before `set_prompt` or remove `DEBUG` trap when running it.

Comment: `Execute history -a for example before set_prompt`: excellent! Thanks for the detailed answer!